# Condition for a complex vector bundle to be holomorphic?

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

Suppose that $(E,\pi,M)$ is a complex vector bundle. I've seen it suggested in a few places that if $E$ and $M$ are complex manifolds, and $\pi$ is a holomorphic map, then $(E,\pi,M)$ is in fact a holomorphic vector bundle. In other words, there exist local trivializations which are biholomorphisms. Is this true?

*Edit:* As explained by Mike Miller in the comments, this cannot be true as stated, because the complex vector bundle might have an "anti-holomorphic" structure to being with. A better question would be whether there is *some* holomorphic vector bundle structure $(E,\pi',M)$, which is isomorphic as a complex vector bundles to $(E,\pi,M)$. Alternatively, one could drop the requirement that $(E,\pi,M)$ be a complex vector bundle, and instead ask what milder conditions (e.g. $\pi$ is a smooth constant rank submersion) would be sufficient to guarantee that $(E,\pi,M)$ is holomorphic (assuming still that $E$ and $M$ are complex manifolds and $\pi$ is holomorphic).

Comment: RE: Edit. Yes. The proof is essentially identical to that of smooth vector bundles having smooth transition maps.

Comment: (If you'd like more explanation than the brief comment, ping me - I'm glad to expound on it tomorrow if nobody else has.)

Comment: Okay, thanks! Can you sketch a proof or cite a source? Definitions that I've seen include smooth (resp. holomorphic) transition functions as part of the requirements for a smooth (resp. holomorphic) vector bundle.

Comment: Oh, I'm very sorry for my previous comments. This is just not true. Take $E = \Bbb C, M = \{pt\}$. Let the scalar multiplication be, like, $(\lambda, z) \mapsto \overline{\lambda} z$. A holomorphic vector bundle would have this map be holomorphic. If you demand in addition to the conditions on $(E,\pi,M)$ that the scalar multiplication $\Bbb C \times E \to E$ and $E \times_M E \to E$ are holomorphic, then it's true that you have holomorphic trivializations/transition functions.

Comment: What I'm not sure about is whether or not there's an example where you can't *give it* the structure of a holomorphic bundle isomorphic to the previous complex vector bundle. So, changing the vector space structure, but in a way that doesn't change the topological type of the complex vector bundle.

Comment: @MikeMiller I apologize for asking this question here but could you give me a reference to the fact you mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: @random123: It also is not correctly stated. You need to assume addition and scalar multiplication as above are smooth. Once you have that, here's the tip: use the inverse function theorem to pick a set of $n$ linearly independent local sections, and use these to exhibit a smooth local trivialization (using that addition and scalar mult. are smooth).

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @MikeMiller I don't fully understand your example, since for me, a complex vector bundle (e.g. following Wikipedia's definition for vector bundles) would require the existence of smooth local trivializations which are complex-linear in the vector space variable, ruling out the kind of anti-holomorphic flipping that you mention. Maybe we are just using different definitions, though---I agree with your second comment that the correctly-posed version of the problem has not been solved yet.

Comment: @MichaelWan: But a trivialization here is just an isomorphism with $\Bbb C$. There is one for two good reasons: $E \to \Bbb C$, $z \mapsto \bar z$, where $E$ is $\Bbb C$ equipped with my scalar multiplication, *is* a complex linear isomorphism. Alternatively: there has to be an iso, because there's only one complex vector space of dimension 1 up to iso!

Comment: Right---thanks! I've edited the question.