# Two definitions of holomorphic vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

I am stuck in the task of understanding of the following. I am trying to learn about holomorphic vector bundle. So far, I have found two definitions.

**Definition 1:** One starts with the complex (smooth or topological, does not matter) vector bundle $\pi: E \rightarrow M$ over the complex manifold $M$, assuming there is a local trivialization of $E$ whose transition maps are holomorphic maps.

**Definition 2:** One again starts with complex vector bundle $\pi: E \rightarrow M$ over the complex manifold $M$, only assuming that there is a *complex structure on $E$* making $\pi: E \rightarrow M$ into a holomorphic map of complex manifolds.

The implication **D1** $\Rightarrow$ **D2** is quite clear, as one can use the local trivialization together with holomorphic atlas on $M$ to define the holomorphic atlas on $E$, such that $\pi$ is locally just a projection.

The definition **D1** is quite common. For example, I use the [Lectures on Kähler Geometry](https://books.google.cz/books?id=oqmroUc9E8YC&printsec=frontcover&dq=moroianu%20complex&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilla26ifPXAhWB6qQKHUirCQ4Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=moroianu%20complex&f=false). On the other hand, in [lecture notes](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/%7Espoho/pdf/notes_8-1.pdf) by Sean Pohorence, they use **D2**. In the first reference, they give the equivalence **D1** $\Leftrightarrow$ **D2** as an excercise.

I am completely stuck in the **D2** $\Rightarrow$ **D1** part. Excercise 2.0.7. in the second reference hints one to show that based on **D2**, every local trivialization map $\phi: U \times \mathbb{C}^{k} \rightarrow \pi^{-1}(U)$ is automatically holomorphic. Clearly, this would prove **D1**. Can someone hint me on this one? Some good reference (at least stating this precisely) would be fine.

Interestingly, there is already some discussion in [this topic here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491886/condition-for-a-complex-vector-bundle-to-be-holomorphic), where people suggest that this implication may not be true, which confuses me even more...

With kind regards, Jan Vysoký

Comment: In **D2**, $E$ is a complex manifold: by definition of complex manifold, $\phi:U\times\mathbb{C}^k\to\pi^{-1}(U)$ is a holomorphic map.

Comment: I understand that E is a  complex manifold, but $\phi$ is by assumption just a diffeomorphism. Why is it a holomorphism?